# Hibernate not creating a new column on different schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Following is the entity in which I've added a new column named `banned`

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistenceUnit")
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "customerDb")
public class CustomerEntity {
private String email;
private String password;
private Timestamp createdAt;
private String secondaryEmail;
private int id;
private Timestamp updatedAt;
private short verified;
private Timestamp lastVisitedAt;
private String name;
private String image;
private String phoneNumber;
private boolean banned;

@Basic
@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 255)
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 80)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = true)
public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Timestamp createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "secondaryEmail", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getSecondaryEmail() {
    return secondaryEmail;
}

public void setSecondaryEmail(String secondaryEmail) {
    this.secondaryEmail = secondaryEmail;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "updatedAt", nullable = true)
public Timestamp getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Timestamp updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "verified", nullable = false)
public short getVerified() {
    return verified;
}

public void setVerified(short verified) {
    this.verified = verified;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "lastVisitedAt", nullable = true)
public Timestamp getLastVisitedAt() {
    return lastVisitedAt;
}

public void setLastVisitedAt(Timestamp lastVisitedAt) {
    this.lastVisitedAt = lastVisitedAt;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "image", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "banned")
public boolean getBanned() {
    return banned;
}

public void setBanned(boolean banned) {
    this.banned = banned;
}
}
```

However, I've configured the datasource on another schema, i.e.

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbdriverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/community__db" />
    <property name="username" value="${db-username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db-password}" />
</bean>
```

Below is the log:

```
19:17:01.951 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  java.sql.DatabaseMetaData - HHH000262: Table not found: customer 
19:17:01.951 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.954 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  java.sql.DatabaseMetaData - HHH000262: Table not found: customer 
19:17:01.955 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  java.sql.DatabaseMetaData - HHH000262: Table not found: customer 
19:17:01.955 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.955 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.955 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory - Setting dialect     [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] 
19:17:01.957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - create table customerDb.customer (Id integer not null, banned TINYINT(1), createdAt datetime, email varchar(255) not null, image varchar(255), lastVisitedAt datetime, name varchar(255), password varchar(80) not null, phoneNumber varchar(45), secondaryEmail varchar(255), updatedAt datetime, verified smallint not null, primary key (Id)) ENGINE=InnoDB 
19:17:01.958 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table customerDb.customer (Id integer not null, banned TINYINT(1), createdAt datetime, email varchar(255) not null, image varchar(255), lastVisitedAt datetime, name varchar(255), password varchar(80) not null, phoneNumber varchar(45), secondaryEmail varchar(255), updatedAt datetime, verified smallint not null, primary key (Id)) ENGINE=InnoDB 
19:17:01.958 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - Table 'customer' already exists 
19:17:01.958 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000232: Schema update complete 
19:17:01.958 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.internal.NamedQueryRepository - Checking 6 named HQL queries
```

Shouldn't a new column be created in the `customer` table? Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tell your JPA provider to UPDATE the table rather than just CREATE a new one?

Comment: @NeilStockton Yup, hbm2ddl.auto is set to update

Answer (score 0):

You already have a customer table, hibernate doesn't know to alter the table, it's just trying to create a new one. If you don't have any useful data just `drop table customer` and rerun.

Also, check permissions for your user and make sure that user can create a table.

I got this from this log message:

```
HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table customerDb.customer  ....
19:17:01.958 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR ..... - Table 'customer' already exists
```

Comment: Why Hibernate does not know to alter table? I cannot drop the table because of the data.

Comment: Also, It is working fine for the schema which has been passed to the datasource.